# Problemas em algoritmo em C

Tags: c

Alguém sabe dizer porque o programa simplesmente fecha quando digito o **O**?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h> //Biblioteca locale é uitlizada para definar o idioma do programa.

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese"); //Comando utilizado para caracteres especiais aparecerem.
    char turno,cargo;
    float sal_min,sal_bruto,horas,vlr_h,imposto,sal_liq;

    printf("Calculo de salário \n\n");
    printf("Digite o numéro de horas trabalhadas: ");
    scanf("%f",&horas);
    printf("Digite o valor do salário mínímo: ");
    scanf("%f",&sal_min);
    printf("\n\n");

    printf("Turnos de trablaho      Valor do coeficiente \n");
    printf("  Matutino - M          10%% do salário mínimo. \n");
    printf("  Vespertino - V        15%% do salário mínimo. \n");
    printf("  Noturno - N           10%% do salário mínimo. \n");

    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Com base na tebela digite a letra referente ao seu turno de trabalho: ");
    scanf("%s",&turno);
    printf("\n\n");

    switch (turno)
    {
//Maturino
    case 'm' :
        vlr_h = sal_min * 0.1;
        sal_bruto = vlr_h * horas;
        printf("Turno matutino \n");
        printf("   Seu salário bruto será de R$ %.2f.",sal_bruto);
        printf("\n\n");

        printf("Calculos de impostos \n\n ");
        printf("Cargos \n");
        printf("    O - Operário \n");
        printf("    G - Gerente \n\n");
        printf("Digite o codigo de seu cargo: ");
        printf("%s",&cargo);

        if (cargo == 'o') {
            if (sal_bruto >= 300)
            {
                imposto = sal_bruto *0.05;
                sal_liq = sal_bruto - imposto;
                printf("Seu salário liquido será de R$ %.2f",sal_liq);
                printf("\n \n");
            }
            else if (sal_bruto <300)
            {
                imposto = sal_bruto *0.03;
                sal_liq = sal_bruto - imposto;
                printf("Seu salário liquido será de R$ %.2f",sal_liq);
                printf("\n \n");
            }
        }
        break;
```

Comment: Leitura de char é feita com `%c` e não `%s`. Comece por ai

Comment: mudei os %s para %c mas agora nem o case m executa mais.

Comment: Isso tem a ver com o facto das leituras anteriores consumirem ou não o `\n`, que no caso o `%f` não consome. Meta um espaço antes do `%c`, assim: `scanf(" %c",&turno);`

Answer (score 0):

```
...
printf("Digite o codigo de seu cargo: ");
printf("%s",&cargo);/* Aqui deve ser a função scanf e não printf, ou se for
 printf tem que tirar o & depois da virgula*/
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Para além das correções sugeridas anteriormente sugiro que utilizes esta linha de código depois dos scanf's. Desta forma consome sempre tudo o que for inserido no buffer até ao '\n' e não terás esse problema.

while(getchar()!='\n');

O teu código corrigido:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h> //Biblioteca locale é uitlizada para definar o idioma do 
programa.

int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese"); //Comando utilizado para caracteres especiais aparecerem.
char turno,cargo;
float sal_min,sal_bruto,horas,vlr_h,imposto,sal_liq;

printf("Calculo de salário \n\n");
printf("Digite o numéro de horas trabalhadas: ");
scanf("%f",&horas);
while(getchar()!='\n');
printf("Digite o valor do salário mínímo: ");
scanf("%f",&sal_min);
while(getchar()!='\n');
printf("\n\n");

printf("Turnos de trablaho      Valor do coeficiente \n");
printf("  Matutino - M          10%% do salário mínimo. \n");
printf("  Vespertino - V        15%% do salário mínimo. \n");
printf("  Noturno - N           10%% do salário mínimo. \n");

printf("\n\n");
printf("Com base na tebela digite a letra referente ao seu turno de 
trabalho: ");
scanf("%c",&turno);
while(getchar()!='\n');
printf("\n\n");

switch (turno)
{
 //Maturino
  case 'm' :
    vlr_h = sal_min * 0.1;
    sal_bruto = vlr_h * horas;
    printf("Turno matutino \n");
    printf("   Seu salário bruto será de R$ %.2f.",sal_bruto);
    printf("\n\n");

    printf("Calculos de impostos \n\n ");
    printf("Cargos \n");
    printf("    O - Operário \n");
    printf("    G - Gerente \n\n");
    printf("Digite o codigo de seu cargo: ");
    scanf("%c",&cargo);
    while(getchar()!='\n');

    if (cargo == 'o') {
        if (sal_bruto >= 300)
        {
            imposto = sal_bruto *0.05;
            sal_liq = sal_bruto - imposto;
            printf("Seu salário liquido será de R$ %.2f",sal_liq);
            printf("\n \n");
        }
        else if (sal_bruto <300)
        {
            imposto = sal_bruto *0.03;
            sal_liq = sal_bruto - imposto;
            printf("Seu salário liquido será de R$ %.2f",sal_liq);
            printf("\n \n");
        }
    }
    break;
    }
}
```